# Percentage padding on nested inline-block elements

Tags: css, percentage

So I came across something I'd not experienced before, but it seems to affect all browsers so I guess correct behaviour I just don't know why.

I have an element `wrapper` which is set to `inline-block`. Inside this wrapper I have three elements which are also set to `inline-block`.

If I set a fixed `padding-right: 10px` on the element then it [works as expected](http://codepen.io/mrchris/pen/emYyRE). However, if I make that padding a percentage `padding-right: 10%`, the last element [always breaks a line](http://codepen.io/mrchris/pen/azbEEG). Why is this?

It works (to some extent) taking the `inline-block` off `wrapper`, but in my design that's quite crucial.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">Link</div><!--
 --><div class="item">Link</div><!--
 --><div class="item">Link</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the display of your item to `inline` instead of `inline-block`

```
.item {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10%;
}
```

To fix the red background issue you can move your color from the background to the item:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.item {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10%;
  background: red;
}
```

JSFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/q7jpa4tn/

Also here is CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYWrXE

CodePen is updated to show what I discussed in the comment as well as the option solution above.

Comment: I said in my question that `inline-block` is important for the '.wrapper' element (where it's part of a bigger design) so that's not an option I'm afraid.

Comment: I am assuming your issue is coming because you don't set the width of the your wrapper.  So you have lets say 100px width set for the wrapper (by default).  Then you add 10% padding twice (to the links), which then pushes the content to take up 120px, and therefore goes outside the background color of your wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwoEew

adding this will fix the problem

you fixed sub with a hack but for parent you did nothing using below method will fix the problem

```
  .wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
   font-size:0; /* for removing children whitespace */
  }

 .item {
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 10%; 
   font-size:15px;
   background: red;
 }

 .wrapper {
   white-space: nowrap; /** will fix the white space **/
 }
```

Comment: The `font-size: 0` is just an alternative to the comment method I used - the end result is the same. The `white-space: nowrap` kind of works but if you leave the background colour on the `wrapper` as opposed to the items then it doesn't fully cover the content: http://codepen.io/mrchris/pen/QwWYoB.

Comment: yes first i also thought the same thing but when i tried reloading and in different browsers it breaks